# How to configure request timeouts in Spring Cloud Gateway via code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to configure request timeouts in code for all routes. I know global timeouts can be configured via following properties in `application.properties`, but how can they be configured in code?

```
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.connect-timeout=1000
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.response-timeout=5s
```

I have looked at `GatewayAutoConfiguration` how timeouts are configured by default. `HttpClientProperties` holds both properties, however it cannot be overwritten.

```
@Bean
public HttpClientProperties httpClientProperties() {
    return new HttpClientProperties();
}
```

Can this be done in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. I created my own bean and used annotation `@Primary` to be able to create a separate bean with the same type. `GatewayAutoConfiguration` now uses my bean instead of the default bean.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public HttpClientProperties overwrittenHttpClientProperties() {
    HttpClientProperties p = new HttpClientProperties();
    p.setConnectTimeout(3000);
    p.setResponseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(10000));
    return p;
}
```